# Exclude files from xcode at compile time recursively

Tags: xcode, build, build-settings

In my project I want to exclude some files for particular configuration.
We can exclude files from xcode at compile time using **Excluded Source file name** build settings.

But this option doesn't work for subfolder/subdirectories.

Is it possible to write a `build-script` to exclude all desired files by giving parent folder name only.

I don't want to change these settings every time when new file is added or deleted in target directory which needs to be excluded at compile time for specific configuration.

What would be the best approach?